# Is the complement of a finite dimensional subspace always closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $F$ be a finite dimensional subspace of an infinite dimensional Banach space $X$, we know that $F$ is always topologically complemented in $X$, that is, there is always a closed subspace $W$ such that $X=F\oplus W$.

I am thinking about the converse. Suppose $W$ is a subspace of $X$ such that $X=F\oplus W$ for some finite dimensional subspace $F$. Is $W$ necessarily closed?

I guess the answer should be negative but I cannot find such an example. Can somebody give a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f:X\to\mathbb C$ is a discontinuous linear functional, then $\ker f$ is not closed.  If $v$ is in $X\setminus \ker f$, then $F=\mathbb C v$ and $W=\ker f$ gives a counterexample.  ($X$ is the internal direct sum of $F$ and $W$ as vector spaces, but it is not a topological direct sum.)

Comment: Thanks! But actually I am thinking about a slightly different problem. Do you mind looking at this earlier post of mine? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158077/finding-the-topological-complement-of-a-finite-dimensional-subspace

Comment: @HuiYu: I just looked there, and it looks like Nate gave it a good answer (after you posted your comment).

Comment: @JonasMeyer If $\dim F= \dim (\mathbb C v) = 1$ then how are you sure that it is complemented with $\ker f$ ? if $\dim (X/\ker f) \ge 2$ then it is not true that $X = F \oplus \ker f$, or did I misunderstood something ?